# I need to write a perl script which will pass value to a shell script

Tags: perl, shell

I have a shell script say **Install.sh** . 
while running this, this will ask several question. like:
Please enter database name, server name etc.
I am not allowed to edit anything in this script.
So I want to write a different perl script or shell script, which will run the install script and pass the default value without asking anything. Basically i am trying to add this in cron.

I searched over the internet, I dint find any solution, dont know its possible or not. Please suggest.

More clarification:

**>> sh Install.sh**

**Please enter the database name :** xyz
**Please enter the server ip :** abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the appropriate respones in a file (e.g. `install.txt`) in the order expected and simply do:

```
./install.sh < ./install.txt
```

Comment: OOO...great...i was not expecting this will be so easy.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try using expect to automate this for you.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Answer (score 0):

Open pipe to that process and then use it.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Bidirectional-Communication-with-Another-Process